# Getting error while running an angular4 existing project in ubntu system

Tags: node.js, angular

I am getting the following error while running the angular4 existing project in my system.

> Error:

```
subrajyoti@subrajyoti-H81M-S:/var/www/html/angular4_project/XSS-DOM/vulnerable$ ng serve
As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release,
which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated
shortly after.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false".

You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command.
```

I have installed `node version 9.4.0 and npm version 5.6.0` and installed the angular cli like this `sudo npm install @angular/cli`. There was a existing project when I run this project by typing the command `ng serve` it gave me the above error. I have already inside the project folder but still getting this error. my package.json file is given below.

```
{
  "name": "crud-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old unsupported version of the CLI. You should update the the latest one or you can migrate it [as described here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update) if you have existing project

Comment: I have already install in root like `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` in my machine.

Comment: what is the version of CLI you have installed?

Comment: I did as per your provided link and now my version is `1.7.1` after that I run that existing code but that error removed but again `Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
    at Class.run (/var/www/html/angular4_project/XSS-DOM/vulnerable/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:51:63)` error is coming.

Comment: I followed `$ sudo rm -rf node_modules,
$ npm install,
$ ng serve` this but same error i.e-`Your global Angular CLI version (1.7.1) is greater than your local
version (1.6.8). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
`.

Comment: First of all remove CLI from local and global and then install again